# Правовые аспекты работы с чужим API

Tags: api, юридические-аспекты, авторские-права

Есть заказ на изготовление iOS приложения. Заказчик предлагает работать с сетевым API которое написано другими людьми для своих сервисов, в частности мобильного приложения. При помощи прокси удалось установить полную структуру API, в том числе проверку на тип клиента (она очень простая). То есть технически - возможность использовать это API есть. Интересуют правовые аспекты данного вопроса. Является ли API защищенным с юридической стороны, либо подключение к чужому API - незаконным?

PS. Мне эта идея не очень нравится как минимум потому что смена API вызовет проблемы в текущем продукте, но вопрос только о правовой стороне.
Благодарю!

Comment: Не силён в юриспруденции, но предположу следующее. Если API не является публичным, то единственный способ, которым вы могли узнать об этом API - это реверс-инженеринг протокола связи приложения с сервером. Обычно в лицензионных соглашениях программ явным образом запрещается реверс-инженеринг как самих программ, так и протоколов связи, используемых в них.

Comment: В данном случае под "лицензионным соглашением" Вами подразумевается публичная оферта по которой распространяются приложения в аппсторе (EULA) ?

Comment: Опять-таки, не силён... Скорее всего именно она и подразумевается. Возможно, для отдельных приложений есть своё соглашение помимо аппсторовского.

Comment: Спросите разработчика API. Если он требует лицензирования — включите стоимость лицензирования в счёт заказчику. Подумайте о том, что делать, если заказчик позже отзовёт заказ.

Comment: >Спросите разработчика API

Самый разумный совет :)

Comment: @VladD, там гарантированно будет непомерно для данного проекта цена за использование апи так как редкие и уникальные данные. Заказчик исходит из того что купить невозможно. К тому же на этом апи строится бизнес оригинального продукта, сомневаюсь что они захотят конкуренцию на своем рынке своими же средствами

Comment: @AlexThumb, ну о какой правовой стороне вы говорите, если даже не попытались поговорить с обладателем API? Может там люди и готовы были бы пойти на сотрудничество, просто они не заложились на то, что это может быть кому-то ещё интересно. А что касается вашего заказчика - он ведь тоже сам себе это в голове нафантазировал. Или предоставил факты? Тогда должен понимать, что это незаконно, и вам не сюда, а на форум "как обойти закон".

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это юридический вопрос, не имеющий непосредственного отношения к программированию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если программа/приложение/API не имеет лицензии или лицензия неизвестна то по умолчанию считается, что *All Rights Reserved*, то есть все права сохранены за автором. По-русски выражаясь, это означает она не разрешена для использования другими лицами.

Таким образом, по сути вы используя API и тем более подвергая ее протокол реверс-инжинирингу совершаете уголовное преступление (если только не для целей изучения и то в некоторых странах даже это запрещено).

В общем вы или найдите лицензию к этому API - для примера [лицензия API Ebay выглядит так](http://developer.ebay.com/join/licenses/individual/) или держитесь от этого дела подальше.